# Meu site foi clonado gostaria de uma ajuda de onde começar a solucionar o problama

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, wordpress

Caros senhores tenho um site, https://torrentfilmesagora.net, esse mes de agosto descobri que estava sendo clonado, sites clone: http://powerofourpotential.org, http://griyaok.com, http://premiercashbacknews.com, descobri atravez do google webmastertools.

tudo que posto e atualizo no meu, o mesmo acontece com os outros dominios.

tentei solucionar o problema, trocando de conta cloudflare, ip da minha hospedagem, mudando de hospedagem importando posts e mídia por xlm, e nada resolveu os sites continua ficando igual ao meu, se alguém ja viu ou ja passou por essa situação, e saber resolver o problema ficarei muito grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Creio que essa pergunta não faça parte do escopo do stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Bom os 3 sites que citou estão dando error 403 Forbidden aqui.
Isso pode ocorrer por alguns fatores: alguém tem acesso ao seu banco de dados e está fazendo uma conexão remota para capturar seus posts (Faça uma edição em algum post antigo e procure ele no site que te clonou e veja se a edição ocorre no outro também).

Outra coisa pode ser a permissão do arquivo de xmlrpc do wordpress, já houveram alguns casos com isso, enfim, boa sorte
e só pra constar, sua pergunta está fora do escopo e não deveria estar aqui no StackOverflow, você deve fazer essas perguntas para algum webmaster ou pedir ajuda da empresa de hospedagem que você está usando :)